# Performance Analysis of DLL called by IIS

Tags: asp.net, profiling

The Performance Wizard in Visual Studio 2012 always seems to want an EXE file that hosts the DLL I want to analyze.  But my project only produces DLLs, no EXE.

In the instrumentation page of the wizard (page 2), I did try to select "An ASP.NET or JavaScript application", entering the URL of the web app, and answered Yes to "You do not have any binaries chosen for instrumentation, do you want to continue?"  The output window had "Analysis failed".

What am I doing wrong?